# Dynamically change knockout component's template

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout JS v3.4.0 with RequireJS v2.3.2.

I'm registering components as a single AMD module, as specified [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#registering-components-as-a-single-amd-module).

Now as it happens, I have a case where a component can have multiple templates and based on a particular condition, I return a specific template. It works flawlessly.

For example,

```
ko.components.register('my-component', { require: 'some/module' });
```

And above registered component is as follows,

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    function MyComponentViewModel(params) {
        // some code here
    }

    return {
        viewModel: MyComponentViewModel,
        template: condition ? '<div> Some template </div>' : '<div> A whole another template </div>'
    };
});
```

Now I've run into a scenario in which that condition might change to user input as a user progresses through the application.

To simulate this, consider,

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
        function MyComponentViewModel(params) {
            // some code here
        }
       condition = true;
       setInterval(function(){
             condition = false;
           }, 1500);
        return {
            viewModel: MyComponentViewModel,
            template: condition ? '<div> Some template </div>' : '<div> A whole another template </div>'
        };
    });
```

How do I change the component's template after it has been bound to DOM?

More importantly, can I change the template without unloading and un-registering the component?

Comment: How about if you made the template a `computed` that responded to `condition`?

Comment: @Roy J I too thought of making it observable or computed, but it doesn't change the template.

Comment: Components aren't really set up to handle that sort of thing. You'll have to use a template binding to swap between named templates, or if your template html is static (doesn't contain bindings) you could use the html binding to display the markup directly.